# Photoshop cc, how to create a layer in exactly rectangle size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2015

after drawing a rectangle, photoshop CC create a new layer containing it. However, the layer size is the canvas size, not the rectangle size, showing as following image.
[image]

However, I want my new layer size is equal to the rectangle. like the following one:

[image]

how can I change my new layer size ?

Comment: Hi remykits, Welcome to GD.SE! The layer size will always be at least the same size of the canvas because layers don't have boundaries. This is a thumbnail to show you the size in comparison to the canvas. If you want the layer size to be the size of the square then you need to change the size of the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is set to draw dixels, which draws on a layer the size of the full canvas.

What you need to do is set you rectangle to draw as a shape layer. With the tool selected, choose **Shape** from the dropdown in the options bar.

[image: draw mode]